# Spark java.io.IOException: Failed to rename S3AFileStatus

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, commit, parquet

I'm writing spark (2.4.4) dataframe to S3 and get sporadic java.io.IOException: Failed to rename S3AFileStatus errors.
Spark is unbundled installed over hadoop 3.1.3.

The error is known and caused by S3 eventual consistency which means possible immediate inconsistency,
for example it is described in [HADOOP-14161](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14161).

However I do use S3guard and detailed debug logs show it is working. I get all the records in the DynamoDB table,DynamoDB metrics shows reads and writes, s3guard info shows it is enabled etc.

I understand that the default file committer is less than ideal, but shouldn't I avoid the problem because S3guard guarantees immediate consistency?

In other words, why do I still get the error despite S3guard?
Thank you in advance for your time!

```
WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager - Lost task 49.0 in stage 936.0 (TID 72604, 10.0.62.191, executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to rename S3AFileStatus{path=s3a://my-spark-bucket/persisted_data/00/c9d61ba03f114d5f937eb8bdbe9ac2bc__9d6ba987-06e1-4e66-be88-f518ede26a4c_/rtg.parquet/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20200123150921_0936_m_000049_72604/part-00049-f9ef3dcb-0928-466d-a663-39f023f401b8-c000.snappy.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=180872; replication=1; blocksize=33554432; modification_time=1579792215000; access_time=0; owner=root; group=root; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=true; isErasureCoded=false} isEmptyDirectory=FALSE to s3a://my-spark-bucket/persisted_data/00/c9d61ba03f114d5f937eb8bdbe9ac2bc__9d6ba987-06e1-4e66-be88-f518ede26a4c__Export/rtg.parquet/part-00049-f9ef3dcb-0928-466d-a663-39f023f401b8-c000.snappy.parquet
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:605)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:568)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Hi @dovka , I am also facing same issue, and I am trying to understand whether S3Guard in my environment is working or not ( I've already verified data in DynamoDB it's writing and verified metrics that shows both reads/writes ) but still not sure why I am seeing error like you've been seeing. Could you please tell me how you enabled logging? Once enabled can you guide me where we can check the logs related to S3Guard?

Comment: I enabled the directory committer - the default  committer is the root cause for the error above. See the instructions for enabling the directory committer here:  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html#Using_the_Directory_and_Partitioned_Staging_Committers

Comment: Thanks @dovka for quick reply, it doesn't work in my case since am using Hadoop 2.6 from CDH 5.16.2.